# How to include <script type> in external .js file?

Tags: javascript, external

I want to include following JS in external .JS file.

```
<script type="text/x-serialization" data-gwd-canvas="serialization">
 //------
</script>
```

How to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to include script tag in external file

Comment: What I need is I want to define attribute type & data-gwd-canvas for the script.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

it's simple

```
<script src="/path/to/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What I need is I want to define attribute type & data-gwd-canvas for the script.
How to do it?

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much. I got it.
I used like below
    <script type="text/x-serialization" data-gwd-canvas="serialization" src="serialize.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
        <script type="text/x-serialization" data-gwd-canvas="serialization" src="path/to/js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case, you can use as always the fantastic free jQuery framework, which let you do the very same thing in one line:`$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded and executed.");
   // Here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script
});`

Answer (score 0):

I used like below

```
<script type="text/x-serialization" data-gwd-canvas="serialization" src="serialize.js"></script>
```